# Many-to-many relationship traversal with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I'm quite new to SQLAlchemy (and I do not have much experience with databases in general). I'm trying to traversere two many-to-many relationships. Given a parent, how can I get all unique grandchildren?

```py
parent_child_table = Table('parent_child', Base.metadata,
    Column('parent_id', Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id')),
    Column('child_id', Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child",
                    secondary=parent_child_table,
                    backref="parents")

child_grandchild_table = Table('child_grandchild', Base.metadata,
    Column('child_id', Integer, ForeignKey('child.id')),
    Column('grandchild_id', Integer, ForeignKey('grandchild.id'))
)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    grandchildren = relationship("Grandchild",
                         secondary=child_grandchild_table,
                         backref="children")

class Grandchild(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'grandchild'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Thanks! This problem is giving me a headache...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forard way:

```
# my_parent = ... (instance of Parent)

q = (session.query(Grandchild)
        .join(Child, Grandchild.children)
        .join(Parent, Child.parents)
        .filter(Parent.id == my_parent.id)
        )
```

`sqlalchemy` will return only unique `Grandchild` instances (although the SQL query does not filter duplicates out).